# a simple question about the detail of proof about linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove that if $W_1$ is any subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ ,
then there exists a subspace $W_2$ of $V$ such that $V = W1 \oplus W2$

I have already proved the statement $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$

But I am curious about that do we need to prove the $W_2$ is also a subspace?

Comment: That depends on how exactly you described the set $W_2$. The only thing that we're given from the question itself is a vector space $V$ and a subspace $W_1$.

Comment: How can you prove $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ without proving that $W_2$ is a subspace? The notation requires both direct summands to be subspaces before you can even use it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin By using definition

Comment: @ident That's Arturo's point. "By using definition" - "the" (usual) definition of a direct sum involves $W_1,W_2$ being subspaces, usually.

Comment: You need to assure that $W_2$ is a subspace. Even if you proved that for every  $v \in V$ there is $w_1 \in W_1 \subset V $ and $w_2 \in W_2 \subset V$ such that $w_1 + w_2 = v$, you STILL have to prove that $W_2$ is a subspace.

Comment: That's my point. The definition **requires** that the two summands be subspaces. If you haven't established that $W_2$ is a subspace, then whatever argument you made to "prove" that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ is incorrect, because you cannot prove that equality without *first* proving that $W_2$ is a subspace.

Comment: Explicitly, if $V$ is a vector space, and $W_1$ and $W_2$ are **subspaces**, we say that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ if and only if $V=W_1+W_2$ and $W_1\cap W_2=\{\mathbf{0}\}$. If you haven't proven that $W_2$ is a subspace, checking that $V=W_1+W_2$ and that $W_1\cap W_2=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ does **not** prove that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$, because the definition presupposes that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$.